# export Mysql table data to CSV with PHP on header without html code

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am trying to export some some data from Mysql with PHP to .CSV file

The issue is script export .CSV file but in the .CSV file before tabels there are HTML  code

***Here you have the script***

```
// Get all fields names in table "mytablename" in database "pendejas".
$fields = mysql_list_fields(pendejas,$table_name);

// Count the table fields and put the value into $columns.
$columns = mysql_num_fields($fields);

// Put the name of all fields to $out.
for ($i = 0; $i < $columns; $i++) {
$l=mysql_field_name($fields, $i);
$out .= '"'.$l.'",';
}
$out .="\n";

// Add all values in the table to $out.
while ($l = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
for ($i = 0; $i < $columns; $i++) {
$out .='"'.$l["$i"].'",';
}
$out .="\n";
}

// Open file export.csv.
$f = fopen ('export.csv','w');

// Put all values from $out to export.csv.
fputs($f, $out);
fclose($f);

header('Content-type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$table_name.csv');
readfile('$table_name.csv');
?>
```

How can i export ONLY  Mysql Table contains ?

appreciate your help

EDIT : SOLVED !

***Here you have script***

```
<?php

$result = mysql_query("SELECT  name, time FROM $table_name");

ob_end_clean();

if ($result) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $pasajeros .= $row["name"] . ";". $row["time"]. "\r\n"; //note the comma here
    }
}
$filename = "pasajeros_" . date("Y-m-d_H-i"); 
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
header("Content-disposition: filename=" . $table_name . ".csv");
print $pasajeros;
exit();

?>
```

Comment: the code seems to open your CSV file afterwards. Have you tried downloading the CSV file to check if it actually contains HTML, or it is being passed from the generating site.

Comment: you must be adding html somewhere, not in the code above.

Comment: i am able to download CSV file but CSV file contains HTML code, code that i have in same PHP file where i export CSV file

Comment: I ve solved finally !!!

here i let the script maybe it can help to someone

<?php

$result = mysql_query("SELECT  name, time FROM $table_name");

ob_end_clean();

if ($result) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $pasajeros .= $row["name"] . ",". $row["time"]. ",\r\n"; //note the comma here
    }
}
$filename = "pasajeros_" . date("Y-m-d_H-i"); 
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
header("Content-disposition: filename=" . $table_name . ".csv");
print $pasajeros;
exit();

?>

Comment: @tao_can, i am really surprised only you and me stumped by the ob_end_clean(). hahahaha. I gave you a thumb up.

Answer (score 0):

At a minimum, just remove this code:

```
// Count the table fields and put the value into $columns.
$columns = mysql_num_fields($fields);

// Put the name of all fields to $out.
for ($i = 0; $i < $columns; $i++) {
$l=mysql_field_name($fields, $i);
$out .= '"'.$l.'",';
}
$out .="\n";
```

As an additional suggestion, you might look into fputcsv to make the process of building the CSV file less manual. This would also help you build your CSV the RIGHT way, which is to NOT build the whole thing in memory and then write the whole thing at once, but rather to write to file one row at a time.  This makes the memory footprint of your script much smaller.